# Can't copy js sources in Chrome 28 Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

On Sources tab I'm trying to copy selected text by pressing Ctrl+C (in Windows),
but text is not being copied, instead I hear standard windows beep sound. If I right click on selected text, there is no copy menu item. It used to work in previous chrome versions.

Chrome vesion is 28.0.1500.72

[image]

And this is context menu 
[image]

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. http://i.imgur.com/3qxEP7z.png

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg♦ Hello, what is your chrome version? Mine is 28.0.1500.72 m. And my context menu is different from yours(see post update)

Comment: I have the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by "**Use CodeMirror editor**" option checked in inspector's settings.
Having this option off resolves the issue (you need to close/open inspector)

It seems like CodeMirror integration is still an early experiment and doesn't do anything useful.